# AWK - replace with sub match

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

How to use `awk` to do replacing with sub match?

I tried:

```
{
fss="FieldsFunc(s string, f bool)"
fss=gensub(/([( ])(.+?) .+?([,)])/,"\\1\\2\\3","g",fss); print fss;
}
```

and am expecting the output to be `FieldsFunc(s, f)`, but I got `FieldsFunc(s string, f)`. What I've done wrong? Thx.

Comment: Works at [regx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/XDcnk4/1)

Comment: I don't think awk supports the non-greedy modifier.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49601/how-to-reduce-the-greediness-of-a-regular-expression-in-awk?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g?awk` doesn't have support for lazniness. Ungreedy quantifiers are Perl specific. You could change your regex to some thing more restrictive:

```
fss = gensub(/(\w+) +\w+([,)])/,"\\1\\2", "g", fss);
```